# Getting an error on running flutter application

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Using Android Studio for Flutter Development...
The error I was getting:

```
Finished with error: **ProcessException**: Process 1. 

 1. "D:\Projects\FlutterAndroidProjects\Calculator\calculator\android\gradlew.bat"
    **exited abnormally**:

 2. Unzipping C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv

**Exception in thread "main"** java.util.zip.ZipException: **error in opening zip file**


 1. at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)



 2. at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)

 3. at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
 4. at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
 5. at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
 6. at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
 7. at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
 8. at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
 9. at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
 10.    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
 11.    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
 12.    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Command: D:\Projects\FlutterAndroidProjects\Calculator\calculator\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

Comment: It's probably a corrupted gradle file. Try removing your gradle zip file in `C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` so it will be downloaded again on the next build.

Answer (score 0):

Might be network issues.

Or try deleting `C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv`.

- If its unix platform try `rm -rf C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv`

Try and check the permissions on the directory.

You can also try upgrading gradle-wrapper.properties.

Lastly, you can also download the gradle distribution manually from the website and place it in `C:\Users\Muhammad_Kamran\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`

Answer (score -1):

This is because the file is corrupted so delete the existing gradle file

.gradle\wrapper\dists will be a hidden file and there will be several such folders in project,android folder and your home

Find the folder and delete the corrupted file and run it

Answer (score -2):

it all about google-services
i change it to google-services:4.2.0 as you said and it work with me .

Comment: But i doesn't work with me. I already changed google-services:4.2.0